# String comparison time complexity lower bound

Tags: string, comparison, time-complexity

Is there a way to compare two strings in a less than linear time complexity O(n + k)?

Comment: Comparing two strings is typically done in *O(min(n, k))*, which is lower than *O(n+k)*

Comment: Could you specify what n and k mean? The lengths of both strings?